# How do I determine problems with bootup based on this bootchart?

Tags: 10.04, boot

So I've been having issues with lots of hard-drive usage during bootup and long bootup lately, and I installed bootchart to get these two bootcharts, but damn are there a lot of unfamiliar system stuff on there, it's hard to tell what is a warning sign, and what is simply normal during boot.

Here is a bootchart with the advantage of a previously packed?/cached? boot:

- [Bootchart 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFVqm.png)

Here is the same bootchart without the advantage of a packed boot:

- [Bootchart 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IKg6.jpg)

Can anyone make suggestions on what this is telling me needs fixing?

Comment: Do you see any disk errors in e.g. `/var/log/syslog`? Is your disk healthy? (see Palimpsest Disk Utility - SMART data)

Comment: I'd suspect a failing hard drive too. Open the disk utility, select your hard drive in the left panel, click on *SMART Data* and check the values for *Reallocated Sector Count*, *Reallocation Count*, *Current Pending Sector Count* - they should be zero. Also, check *Load/Unload Cycle Count* (should be below 600,000) and *Power-On Hours* (personally I replace HDDs after 10,000 hours).

Comment: Ouch, my syslog has a constant barrage of:

 - upstart-udev-bridge[22236]: Disconnected from Upstart
 - upstart-udev-bridge main process (21779) terminated with status 1
 - upstart-udev-bridge main process ended, respawning

Comment: Constant and ongoing barrage, that is.

Comment: I guess I'll make another question with that as a topic?

Comment: aha! I think that I've found the source of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So upstart-udev-bridge is a transitional software package to start things up until init gains the ability to do so for itself.

udev deals with starting up devices, it has been known to relate to cdroms, and other hardware devices presumably.

I learned that you can "monitor it" using udevadm monitor.

Here is what I found:

```
udevadm monitor
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[1309201501.345628] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0 (power_supply)
UDEV  [1309201501.346393] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0 (power_supply)
KERNEL[1309201502.364125] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0 (power_supply)
UDEV  [1309201502.365439] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0 (power_supply)
```

...repeat forever.

So it's checking for my battery, which somehow one day decided that it wasn't going to be recognized any more.  Since a battery is a nice thing to have, I think that it checks on a frequent basis when it can't find one on the laptop.

Sooo, it seems to be a hardware problem that may be resolved when I obtain a working battery for this laptop.